# I was looking for "theme-frontend-luma" file in vendor/magento folder

Tags: magento2

As we will be extending the parent theme blank/luma from vendor/magento folder, while I was learning magento2 I can't seem to find the actual location of parent themes blank and luma

I tried googling and it doesn't helped

Answer (score 0):

You will find that file under magento's root directory/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma.

and if you want to create new theme using this parent themes just enter below line in your custom theme's theme.xml file.

```
 <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
```